# Instanciando uma classe podendo utilizá-la em todas as funções da mesma classe

Tags: php, instanciar-objeto

Gostaria de saber se eu posso instanciar uma outra classe apenas uma vez e utilizá-la em todos as outras funções da minha classe atual.

Código de exemplo:

```
require ('model.php');
class search{
    function __construct(){
        $objModel = new Model();}
    function insert(){
        $nome = "Alguém";
        $objModel->inserir($nome);}

    function select(){
        $idade = 30;
        $objModel->buscar($idade);}
}
```

Quando tento fazer isso retorna um erro informando que as variáveis $objModel que estão dentro dos métodos não foram inicializadas.
Gostaria de resolver isso sem ter que colocar um `$objModel = new Model()` em cada função, se é que é possível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente declarar a variável `$objModel` como um atributo da classe e fazer chamada usando o `$this->objModel`:

```
class search{
    private $objModel;
    function __construct(){
        $this->objModel = new Model();
    }
    function insert(){
        $nome = "Alguém";
        $this->objModel->inserir($nome);
    }
    function select(){
        $idade = 30;
        $this->objModel->buscar($idade);
    }
}
```